# prevent user from being able to close command prompt

Tags: c++

Is there a way to prevent the user from closing the command prompt until the program finishes running?  For example if there is a countdown timer that displays on the command prompt output , I want to make closing the command prompt by clicking the X impossible until the program finishes running.

Comment: You really, really don't want to do this, no matter how much you think you do. The command prompt window itself is another program, that the user has consciously started up and wants control over. Imagine if I wrote a Flash game that somehow prevented you from closing your web browser until you quit the game - how would you feel about that? I would **hope** you would be cursing both at me for doing it, and Adobe for making it possible for me to do it.

Comment: Even if you could do THAT, the user can always kill the program from task manager.

Comment: It would be better to simply display a confirmation box asking whether the user really wants to close the application - this would tend to prevent users accidentally terminating the program, while not removing control from the user.

Comment: @user505255 IIRC it doesn't work that way for console apps. And Windows apps will "return" to console when run from there, while still running.

Comment: You could be right, I've never written a Windows console app.

Comment: Guys the point of preventing the user from being able to close is so they cannot abuse the timer...close it and start it up again.  The point of the timer is to limit the amount of time they spent on the computer..I do not want the user to be able to close the program and start it again, reseting the time.

Comment: @Jake - Is this because you charge per hour, or because you want to force a poor kid to go watch TV instead?

Comment: no charge haha, pretty much the second option although its more to let other kids in the classroom use the computer as well

Comment: @Jake perhaps a console app ISN'T how you should approach this issue then. If you want the user to be unable to terminate the program, I'd suggest writing it as a Windows service that does the real work, with a regular Windows app to communicate with and show output from the service. It's far more bulletproof than trying to lock down a command prompt window, or even writing the same app as a regular Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab hold of the mouse so the user can't move it, or click.
But then they could use keyboard shortcuts to do the same, so you need to lock out the keyboard as well.

Sometimes you want to do these sorts of things when your performing automation, say performing SSO on an app that needs raw keyboard input and forground focus.  You can't let the user change the focus or type something at the same time.  But you do that as a last resort.